# Error Unexpected end of input with the correct brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I write to gallery and a script for her. An error `Unexpected end of input` occurs, and I don't know how to fix it.

One of the options offered by Google was a problem with the brackets.
'Brackets checked several times'.  A similar code worked earlier. With what it can be connected and how to fix it?

```
(function () {
    var $window = $(window),
            flexslider;
    function getGridSize() {
        return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 3 :
                (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 4 :
                (window.innerWidth > 900) ? 6 : 7;
    }
    $(function () {
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        var flexslider =''; 
        $('#carousel').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 110,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: '#slider',
            minItems: getGridSize(), 
            maxItems: getGridSize()
        });
        $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshowSpeed: 3000,
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            //slideshow: false,
            sync: "#carousel",
            start: function (slider) {
                if(window.innerWidth <= 800){
                        jQuery(".slides").removeClass("adjusted_width");    
                }
                jQuery('.icon-pause').click(function () {
                    jQuery(this).hide();
                    jQuery('.icon-play').show();
                    slider.pause();
                });
                jQuery('.icon-play').click(function () {
                    jQuery(this).hide();
                    jQuery('.icon-pause').show();
                    slider.play();
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $window.resize(function () {
        var gridSize = getGridSize();

        flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
        flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
    });
}());
```

Comment: The code sample you posted is fine, syntactically. Are you sure it's that which is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, I put a piece of code to test :D

Answer (score 0):

I think something missing in first line before `(function () {`

OR

in lastline `}());` its should be `}(jQuery));` if this code for custom jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget `</script>` at the end of your script?
In such cases use IDE like WebStorm, it will show you when you're wrong.

Also your code invokes outer functions like `SyntaxHighlighter` (with possible errors there). See error stack.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks for answers.* Nothing helped.

I hate those moments, but **it is no reason** earned.
I'm shocked